# Attach files using org-mu4e

Tags: org-mode, mu4e

I am currently using org-mu4e with

```lisp
(setq org-mu4e-convert-to-html t)
```

and `(org-mu4e-compose-org-mode)`. When I attach files to a email I get the classical

```html
<#part type="application/type" filename="/somepath/somefile" disposition=attachment description=somedescription>
<#/part>
```

inserted into the body, but when org-mode converts the body to html it somehow does nothing and the actual email displays the code `<#part.... #/part>` without including any file. Is there any workaround? I need the option `org-mu4e-convert-to-html` since I use LaTeX in my emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the html code in

```
#+begin_export html
#+end_export
```

block so that it is exported to html format via babel.

Edit: I wrote "src" instead of export by mistake .

Comment: That didn't work sadly

Comment: Fixed it in the next answer. Thanks.

Comment: It also didn't work for me. I'm starting to think that it is impossible to add an attachment with org-mime. I am on mu4e 1.5.3.

Answer (score -1):

The actual solution is to enclose the `<#part ...>` tag like this:

```
#+BEGIN_EXPORT html
 <#part ...> <#/part>
#+END_EXPORT
```